# Two column page with bootstrap v3.3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve a two column page in bootstrap just like in this webpage. I am new to bootstrap and just learnt about the grid. I thought of doing like below.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I divide the page into left and right in the range of 8-4. However, i noticed when my rows in left increases, it pushes the right down. Then i thought maybe they cant be in the same row. I tried like below.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>HTML</h2>
                <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
                <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>HTML</h2>
                <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
                <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

When i put in a separate row, i couldn't achieve the two columns. I tried

```
<div class="row-right">
<div class="col-right col-md-4">
```

All thinking that should work base on the documentation or the little i learnt yet nothing change. Please help i want it to be like in this page http://www.stjobs.sg/singapore-jobs/retail-merchandising-job?

**Update**

below is the whole script .

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>


         <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fixed col-sm-12">
            <footer>
                <p>© Copyright 2013 Tutorial Republic</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first is correct, add a .container around the .row but don't nest .container. The second is incorrect.

Comment: Hi christina. THere is a container around .row . It contain all the contents including the footer. What do you mean by dont nest ? can you please give me example ?

Comment: Then you did it correctly. You just don't put a container inside a container or a container-fluid inside a container-fluid it's in the docs. You did a good job on the first example, this is the way to do two columns on 992px and up.

Comment: The last one is incorrect see comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more simple than you think. All content should either go on one column and the rest on the other column:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-8">
      ALL CONTENT HERE
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
      OTHER CONTENT HERE
  </div>

</div>
```

You **do not** have to put any further col-md-8 and col-md-4 in other divs for your layout. Just put your content without any classes.

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8">
          <h2>My Heading</h2>
          <p>My text.</p>

          <h2>My Heading</h2>
          <p>My text.</p>

          <h2>My Heading</h2>
          <p>My text.</p>

          <h2>My Heading</h2>
          <p>My text.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>My Heading</h2>
          <p>My text.</p>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Also in my attempt to make it responsive i use this . Is it correct ? `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-8">` and  `<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4">` respectively . please are those correct?

Comment: You don't need to use md and lg at the same time. You can just use md if you want. And col-xs-0 doesn't exist. If you wish to put the sidebar below the main content, use col-xs-12 for it as well. If you want to hide it, you can use display: none in css.

Comment: Oh i just learnt the xs,sm,md and the lg. if i use md only, wouldn't that affect the responsiveness on large screens ? also what abt the xs, sm etc i used? are they not necessary as well?

Comment: What's the downvote for? 

No, it won't have an effect. 

From bootstrap site:
Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.

Comment: Thanks man . Btw i didn't downvote you. so i should remove the lg and leave the rest ? thank you for your time .

Comment: Yes and remove col-xs-0.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct (assumes .container around the content):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

The second examples is not correct according to the docs and the way it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, can you see the whole script above, My problem is it pushes the  right column to the last left column down. Like it takes the whole as a single row instead of two separate columns

Comment: No that is wrong. There are 12 columns per row. You would do it like this: http://jsbin.com/bikaki all the content goes inside either column you don't re-write the columns again.

Comment: GetBootstrap.com has lots of examples and other instructions.

Comment: oic. So that means i have to add an empty right column for each row? Is that the best way to achieve this or is there any better way christina?

Comment: I don't know what layout you're trying to get but there's only 12 columns per row. If you want two columns you would put the wide content inside the col-X-8 and the sidebar in the col-X-4 and that's all there is. There is no need to make any empty columns. Look at the html on this page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/

Comment: Also in my attempt to make it responsive i use this . Is it correct ? `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-8">` and  `<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4">` respectively . please are those correct?